# opengl matrix multiplication

Tags: opengl, matrix, c

Can someone provide some type of example of multiplying a 4x4 matrix without using loops?

```
typedef struct matrix4
{
    data[16];
} m4;
```

can someone provide a sample of how you you'd multiply two of these in the opengl column major way?

Comment: Multiply a 4x4 matrix with what? With another 4x4 matrix? Of course, you dont have to use loops if the matrix dimensions are specified in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In matrix multiplication, each index in the resulting matrix is the dot product of the ith row in matrix A and the jth column in matrix B:

```
Cij = A.row( i ) . B.col( j );
```

Say we have this matrix, which represents indices in row-major representation,

```
Indices in row-major representation

 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

In row-major it will be stored in an array and elements belonging in the same row will be stored sequentially.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ... 15
```

In column-major it's the opposite, elements in the same column will be stored sequentially.

```
0, 4, 8, 12, 1, 5, 9, 13, 2, 6, 10, 14, 3, 7, 11, 15
```

This corresponds to transposing the row-major matrix. Multiplying two transposed matrices is the same as transposing after multiplying them. So in the end you can multiply column-major matrices in the exact same way as you multiply row-major matrices.

Still I'll show you how to multiply in the "column-major way".
If we transpose the matrix above, you can easily see which linear indices correspond to which matrix index in the column-major representation,

```
Indices in column-major representation

0  4  8 12  // Indices 0,4,8,12 are the first row
1  5  9 13  // Indices 0,1,2,3 the first column, etc
2  6 10 14
3  7 11 15
```

For example, the value in (0,0) and (2,2) can be calculated like this

```
C00 = C[0] = A[0] * B[0] + A[4] * B[1] + A[8] * B[2] + A[12] * B[3]
C22 = C[10]= A[2] * B[8] + A[6] * B[9] + A[10] * B[10] + A[14] * B[11]
```

And I'll leave the remaining indices for you.